# Does the continuity equation for fluids simply state that the material derivative of density is 0?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, density

The definition of material derivative is:

$$\frac{Df}{Dt}:= \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+(\vec{v} \ \cdot \vec{\nabla})f $$

And the continuity equation is:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}(\rho\vec{v})=0$$

If $f=\rho$, then it seems to me that the continuity equation is simply the material derivative of $\rho$ set to $0$. That is, stating that the density of a fixed volume element is constant since the amount of mass "going in" and "going out" is the same, thus the $M/V$ ratio is fixed. Is this explanation, albeit probably too simplified, correct?  And more importantly, is the continuity equation indeed just a statement for the material derivative of density?

Comment: Yes you can say the changes in the density are entirely due to the motion of the fluid.